# how do i log full http request using log4net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, logging, log4net

I want to be able to log the full HTTP request with values with every error message that i log. Current conversion pattern i have looks like this -

```
<conversionPattern value="%date{G} [%thread] %-5level
          [%aspnet-request{AUTH_USER}] [%aspnet-request{REMOTE_ADDR}] 
           %newline%message%newline
           ALL_RAW::%aspnet-request{ALL_RAW}
           %newline%newline%newline" />
```

Which gives me an output like follows

```
06/19/2015 11:56:02 [60] INFO  [user@email.com] [mo-machine]
MESSAGE :: BOOMMMM
ALL_RAW :: Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Host: localhost:43899
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.124 Safari/537.36
CSP: active
Origin: chrome-extension://fhbjghcddcbncdddomop
Postman-Token: 38f023c1-3298-5726-e43f-650bab852cf2

URL :: POST localhost:43899 /controller/test InternalID=10124&MID=0921&Detail&OrgID=14347
```

I am still missing the post body, How do i get the raw post body in the log as well? Is there a better way to do this and log the whole HTTP request with all the parameters and the body posted logged correctly?

Comment: did u get anywhere with this?

Comment: no - never figured it out. Found other tools that do this, but not using log4net. But only for error logging.

Comment: Which is that tool, @MoXplod?

Comment: right now we are using a paid tool - raygun